# Checked styles by default

Tags: sxa, css

Is there a way styles can be checked by default?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide information on what SXA component are you using?

Comment: I am using the Tab component @VadimBirkos

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The steps to take:

1. Determine the `GUID` of the style you want to select: search the style item in `$site/Presentation/Styles`
2. Make sure the `rendering parameters` template of your component has standard values
3. In those standard values, set the view to "raw values" (you can do so in the View ribbon)
4. In the `Styles` field (in the Styling section) you set the guid of the style item (e.g. {E06D21CA-9971-4FB2-B579-D4DBCE4EA443}) and save.
5. Uncheck the raw values
6. Test... (add the component somewhere)

Comment: Sorry, I followed your steps but it didn't work. I don't get it why I need to set the guid of the style item? All I need is to make the checkbox checked by default. Currently all the checkboxes are unchecked

Comment: You need to set the guid because you are working with the raw values. I just tested this (again) and it worked. Are you sure you've got the correct guid in the correct field of the correct standard values item?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the item ID (`GUID`) of your Style item.
2. Go to the template of the rendering that you wish to apply this change (`/sitecore/templates/Feature/(template folder)/(rendering section folder)/Rendering Parameters/(Select the rendering)`). Make sure it has standard values
3. Go to the View ribbon and select "**Raw values**"
4. Select `_Standard Values` and go to the content section. Under Styling, there is a field called "**Styles**". Put your style item id (`GUID`) and save.
5. Uncheck the raw values option.

Now when you add the component on the page, by default that style class is selected.